# How to replace overlapping strings in Javascript without destroying the HTML structure

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a string and an array of N items:

```html
<div>
sometimes the fox can fly really high
</div>
```

```js
const arr = ['the fox can', 'fox can fly', 'really high']`
```

I want to find a way to replace the text inside the div with HTML to highlight those specific phrases inside the array without breaking the HTML. This can be problematic because I can't do a simple loop and replace because then other words will not match after a replacement because the highlight span would break something like `indexOf` or `includes` on the `innerHTML`, sure I can use `innerText` to read the text but it doesn't provide anything that makes it so I can add the "next" span without breaking the original HTML highlights. Ideally, I also want to be able to customize the class name depending on the word I use rather than just a generic highlight class too.

The outcome should be

```html
<div>
sometimes
<span class="highlight-1">the <span class="highlight-2">fox can</span></span><span class="highlight-2"> fly</span> <span class="highlight-3">really high</span>
</div>
```

**What have I tried?**

I've really thought about this and cannot find any resources online that help with this scenario and the main, Currently, I also need extra values such as `charStart` and `charEnd` of the word, I don't like this solution because it depends on using the `DOMParser()` API and it feels really hacky, definitely isn't performant and I just get a "vibe" that I shouldn't be doing this method and there must be better solutions, I am reaching out to SO for ideas on how I can accomplish this challenge.

```js
      let text = `<p id="content">${content}</p>`
      let parser = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, "text/html")

      for (const str of strings) {
        const content = parser.querySelector("#content")
        let descLength = 0

        for (const node of content.childNodes) {
          const text = node.textContent

          let newTextContent = ""

          for (const letter in text) {
            let newText = text[letter]
            if (descLength === str.charStart) {
              newText = `<em class="highlight ${str.type}" data-id="${str.id}">${text[letter]}`
            } else if (descLength === str.charEnd) {
              newText = `${text[letter]}</em>`
            }

            newTextContent += newText
            descLength++
          }

          node.textContent = newTextContent
        }

        // Replace the &lt; with `<` and replace &gt; with `>` to construct the HTML as text inside lastHtml
        const lastHtml = parser
          .querySelector("#content")
          .outerHTML.split("&lt;")
          .join("<")
          .split("&gt;")
          .join(">")

        // Redefine the parser variable with the updated HTML and let it automatically correct the element structure
        parser = new DOMParser().parseFromString(lastHtml, "text/html")

        /**
         * Replace the placeholder `<em>` element with the span elements to prevent future issues. We need the HTML
         * to be invalid for it to be correctly fixed by DOMParser, otherwise the HTML would be valid and *not* render how we'd like it to
         * Invalid => `<span>test <em>title </span>here</em>
         * Invalid (converted) => `<span>test <em>title </em></span><em>here</em>
         * Valid => `<span>test <span>title </span>here</span>
         */

        parser.querySelector("#content").innerHTML = parser
          .querySelector("#content")
          .innerHTML.replaceAll("<em ", "<span ")
          .replaceAll("</em>", "</span>")
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go over your example just to give an idea. Below code is not a clean function, please adjust it according to your needs.

```
const str = "sometimes the fox can fly really high";
const arr = ['the fox can', 'fox can fly', 'really high'];

// First, find the indices of start and end positions for your substrings.
// Call them event points and push them to an array.
eventPoints = [];
arr.forEach((a, i) => {
  let index = strLower.indexOf(a)
  while (index !== -1) {
    let tagClass = `highlight-${i}`
    eventPoints.push({ pos: index, className: tagClass, eventType: "start" })
    eventPoints.push({ pos: index + a.length, className: tagClass, eventType: "end" })
    index = strLower.indexOf(a, index + 1)
  }
  return
});

// Sort the event points based on the position properties
eventPoints.sort((a, b) => a.pos < b.pos ? -1 : a.pos > b.pos ? 1 : 0);

// Init the final string, a stack and an index to keep track of the current position on the full string
let result = "";
let stack = [];
let index = 0;
// Loop over eventPoints
eventPoints.forEach(e => {
    // concat the substring between index and e.pos to the result
    result += str.substring(index, e.pos);
    if (e.eventType === "start") {
        // when there is a start event, open a span
        result += `<span class="${e.className}">`;
        // keep track of which span is opened
        stack.push(e.className);
    }
    else {
        // when there is an end event, close tags opened after this one, keep track of them, reopen them afterwards
        let tmpStack = [];
        while (stack.length > 0) {
            result += "</span>";
            let top = stack.pop();
            if (top === e.className) {
                break;
            }
            tmpStack.push(top);
        }
        while (tmpStack.length > 0) {
            let tmp = tmpStack.pop();
            result += `<span class="${tmp}">`;
            stack.push(tmp);
        }
    }
    index = e.pos;
});

result += str.substring(index, str.length)


console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for spending the time on this answer, I like the idea you have with the stack and the temporary stack to reopen the appropriate spans. The only change I had to make was adding `result += str.substring(index, str.length)` before returning `result`, otherwise unless the string ends one of the array items it will not include the rest of the string. Thank you!

Comment: I did a little more testing and also realised that it does not detect if the string appears multiple times, but looping through the indexOf was easy enough.

Comment: You're very welcome, glad to hear it helped. And you're right with your points, thank you for the edits:)